# HornetQ : How to read DLQ details

Tags: jboss6.x, hornetq

I would like to read the number of messages sent to the DLQ in hornetq.

Using CLI commands, the jms.queue.DLQ does not appear after : 
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=

Even if it's configured as DLQ for the testQueue

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "consumer-count" => 0,
        "dead-letter-address" => "jms.queue.DLQ",
        "delivering-count" => 0,
        "durable" => true,
        "entries" => [
            "queue/test",
            "java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"
        ],
        "expiry-address" => "jms.queue.ExpiryQueue",
        "message-count" => 0L,
        "messages-added" => 0L,
        "paused" => false,
        "queue-address" => "jms.queue.testQueue",
        "scheduled-count" => 0L,
        "selector" => undefined,
        "temporary" => false
    }
}
```

Enviroment: jboss 6.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `DLQ` does not appear because is just an address and not a physical destination. The same situation occurs with the `ExpiryQueue`. You have to create first these 2 queues. Please find below the corresponding CLI commands:

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=deadLetterQueue:add(entries=["queue/deadLetterQueue"],durable=false)

/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=expiryQueue:add(entries=["queue/expiryQueue"],durable=false)
```